# iptables block traffic on 443 port without connection timeout

Tags: linux, iptables, connection

I have a pc 192.168.1.10 and I want to block traffic to port 443 from the lan to it.

Now I am just using:

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -s 192.168.1.0/24 --dport 443 -j REJECT
```

the problem is that if I point a browser to `https://192.168.1.10` it takes some time to go in connection timeout instead of giving me instantly connection refused as I was expecting from the -j REJECT action.

Why ?  I would like to get a connection refused with the iptables rules that I set and not a connection timeout with some delay.

Thanks

UPDATE: iptables rules:

```
Chain INPUT (policy DROP 1 packets, 36 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
    0     0 DROP       tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcpflags:! 0x17/0x02 state NEW
    0     0 DROP       tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcpflags: 0x3F/0x29
    0     0 DROP       tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcpflags: 0x3F/0x3F
    0     0 DROP       tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcpflags: 0x3F/0x00
    0     0 DROP       tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcpflags: 0x06/0x06
    0     0 DROP       tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcpflags: 0x03/0x03
    0     0 DROP       tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcpflags: 0x11/0x01
    0     0 DROP       tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcpflags: 0x3F/0x37
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       127.0.0.0/24         0.0.0.0/0
    0     0 ACCEPT     udp  --  *      *       127.0.0.0/24         0.0.0.0/0
    9   468 REJECT     tcp  --  *      *       192.168.1.0/24       0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:443 reject-with icmp-admin-prohibited
    0     0 REJECT     tcp  --  tun0   *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:443 reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
   70  4080 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       192.168.1.0/24       0.0.0.0/0
   37  9773 ACCEPT     udp  --  *      *       192.168.1.0/24       0.0.0.0/0
    0     0 ACCEPT     udp  --  eth0   *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:67
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  tun0   *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
    0     0 ACCEPT     icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            icmptype 0
    0     0 ACCEPT     icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            icmptype 3
    0     0 ACCEPT     icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            icmptype 11
    0     0 ACCEPT     icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            icmptype 8 limit: avg 10/sec burst 5
    0     0 DROP       icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
    6   456 ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            state RELATED,ESTABLISHED

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  eth0   tun0    0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  *      eth0    10.7.7.0/24          0.0.0.0/0

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 94 packets, 14132 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
```

Comment: Do a packet capture anyway to see exactly what happens, which packets go through or not, etc. In all cases, always useful to learn new things.

Comment: I tried using tcpdump but I am not able to see what happens. It's still the same with the options you suggest me

Comment: What packet(s) does the server send back to clients attempting to reach port 443?

Comment: @PatrickMevzek the server doesn't answer anything, at least from what I see with tcpdump -n port 443,  the clients continue to connect until the timeout

Comment: Server should reply with some kind of ICMP message (broaden your tcpdump filter to see it) otherwise if the client receives absolutely nothing it will retry, this is the normal/usual behavior. Make sure not to filter ICMP messages anywhere on your network (a usual mistake). In fact you have multiple ACCEPT/DROP rules for icmp messages, study them in relation with what you put in `--reject-with` (you may try `tcp-reset` value, even if less perfect solution)

Comment: @PatrickMevzek ok I am able to see a lot of icmp message unreachable - admin prohibited response but still It goes in connection timeout, even disabling firewall on client

Comment: @PatrickMevzek tcp-reset seems to work!  Why you say it's not a good solution?

Comment: Correct signaling uses ICMP normally, it is a protocol specifically tailored to that. You may get a TCP reset for many other reasons, not necessarily saying that the connection is prohibited, just because nothing listens on this port for example. So it makes troubleshooting more complicated. See https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-choose-an-effective-firewall-policy-to-secure-your-servers#dropping-vs-rejecting-traffic

Comment: @PatrickMevzek if you write an answer from the comments you wrote here I will accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on further exchanges, it appears that there was a need of adding:

```
--reject-with tcp-reset
```

to your `iptables ... -j REJECT` rule, in order to have immediate reaction, without  waiting  for a timeout.

Even if it would have been better to use a specific ICMP based type of rejection, as this protocol is tailored for signaling the reason of the connection refusal.